# java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length

Tags: java, javafx, certificate, javafx-8, x509certificate

I'm trying to create a Java application that can read x509 certificates informations and display them in a `TableView`.

But i've a problem when i'm trying to display those informations with the code below

```
@FXML
private void handleHDD() throws CertificateException, IOException{
    String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File folder = new File(userDir +"\\Desktop\\Certificate_Folder");
    File[] certificates = folder.listFiles();
    if (certificates!=null){

        String columnHeader[] = {"Nom","Version","N°série","Algorithme de signature","Emetteur","Valide à partir de","Valide jusqu'au","Objet","Clé publique"};

        int sizeColumns = 9;

        for (File file : certificates){
            if(file.isFile()){
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(input);
            input.close();
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeColumns; j++) {
                data.add(new CertificateModel(file.getName().replace(".der", ""),cert.getVersion(),cert.getSerialNumber().toString(),cert.getSigAlgName(),cert.getIssuerDN().toString(),cert.getNotBefore(),cert.getNotAfter(),cert.getSubjectDN().toString(),cert.getPublicKey().toString()));
                TableColumn col = new TableColumn();
                col.setText(columnHeader[j]);
                col.setMinWidth(200);
                col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CertificateModel, String>(columnHeader[j]));
                table.getColumns().addAll(col);
            }               
            table.setItems(data);

            }


            }

        }
    }
```

When i try to execute it, i hav the following exception: `java.security.cert.CertificateException`

---

This is the full exception stack:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:198)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:102)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at cm.camgovca.view.CertificateOverviewController.handleHDD(CertificateOverviewController.java:98)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:582)
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:252)
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getDerValue(DerInputStream.java:451)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1784)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
    ... 46 more
```

The line 98 of CertificateOverview.java is

```
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(input);
```

And my certificate is DER Encoded (.der)

Comment: Your certificate file is not in the expected format.

Comment: can you provide the exception stack in your answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`CertificateFactory#generateCertificate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificate(java.io.InputStream)) it says:

> Throws: CertificateException - on parsing errors.

So, as suggested in the comments, most probably your certificate file is not in the expected format.

Especially the following line in the documentation may be of interest:

> In the case of a certificate factory for X.509 certificates, the certificate provided in inStream must be DER-encoded and may be supplied in binary or printable (Base64) encoding. If the certificate is provided in Base64 encoding, it must be bounded at the beginning by -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----, and must be bounded at the end by -----END CERTIFICATE-----.

If you post an exception stack, with detailed exception messages, we probably can help more.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a keystore defined, make sure that it is where you have defined and that the application can read it.

In my case the hint was a bit lower down in the stack trace ("java.security.KeyStore.load"):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length
at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:582) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:391) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:332) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1938) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:67) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
```